# MAX SAT prob- polynomial time

Tags: algorithms

In the MAX SAT problem, we are given a set of clauses.
$$\sum_{j=1}^m 1-(\tfrac12)^{k_j} \; \ge m/2

Comment: What are your thoughts? For example if you do "the stupidest thing you can think of that doesn't _obviously_ lead nowhere" in (a), where do you get stuck?

Comment: b is more of a question to me than a

Comment: And what are your thoughts on that, then?